# Changing workflow IF-conditions from a string runtime

Tags: linq, workflow-foundation-4

I want to be able to change the condition statement of a WF4 Workflow If-Activtity runtime, where the input comes from some sort of user interface as a string. I have read up on how to [change a Workflow dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734569.aspx), or how to create [Activites from code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807392.aspx) - the problem comes when I get to the point of assigning the Condition-property to the If-activity class. My source is a string. [The constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.if.aspx) does not take a string.

Do I have to convert the string to an `Expression<bool>` first? How do I do that?

[image: I want to expose this condition string to the user directly, and have code altering the workflow accordingly]

*This is the string I want to expose*

Note: I realize there may be other ways to accomplish what I want, like (1) create code that alters the XAML of the Workflow instead of the objects, or (2) exposing the entire Workflow editor to the end user. Before I go down that road, I want to know if it is possible to do it my way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a expression like

```
new VisualBasicValue<bool>("Person.Gender = \"Male\"")
```

**A warning:** The *Apply Workflow Changes to Workflows* you are pointing to is about **WF3** and has no bearing in **WF4** whatsoever. With WF4 there is no possibility to dynamically change a running workflow instance. That capability is going to be added in the .NET 4.5 framework.

Comment: Thank's for the heads up on dynamically changing running workflows.

Comment: Took me a couple hours to find this and can't believe it was that simple! Thanks @Maurice.